# Merge data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question regarding a specific type of merge using data.frame in R (found a lot of similar problems, but couldn't get it to work for my specific problem)

Suppose I have two dataframes with tow columns X1,X2 each:

df1 =

```
            X1         X2
    1  '01.01.2000'    4
    2  '01.01.2001'    5
    3  '01.01.2002'    6
```

df2 =

```
            X1         X2
    1  '01.01.2002'    8
    2  '01.01.2003'    9
    3  '01.01.2004'    10
```

What I want is a merged dataframe according to the following rules:

1. If a value in `X1` is only in `df1`, use the value of `X2` in `df1`
2. If a value in `X1` is in both `df1` and `df2` use the value of `X2` from `df2`
3. If a value in `X1` is only in `df2`, use the value of `X2` in `df2`

For `df1` and `df2` above, this would mean:

dfMerged =

```
            X1         X2
    1  '01.01.2000'    4
    2  '01.01.2001'    5
    3  '01.01.2002'    8
    4  '01.01.2003'    9
    5  '01.01.2004'    10
```

Currently, I'm using a very slow solution by merging first and then iterating over all rows. Also tried various approaches using dplyr::Union etc, but couldn't find a proper solution. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following. It just row binds the data.frames and in case of duplicates (based on X1) the row of df1 will be removed.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c("01.01.2000", "01.01.2001", "01.01.2002"),
                  X2 = c(4, 5, 6), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(X1 = c("01.01.2002", "01.01.2003", "01.01.2004"),
                  X2 = c(8, 9, 10), stringsAsFactors = F)

dfMerged <- bind_rows(df2, df1) %>% 
  distinct(X1, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(X1, X2)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(X1 = c("01.01.2000", "01.01.2001", "01.01.2002"), 
                      X2 = 4:6), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(X1 = c("01.01.2002", "01.01.2003", "01.01.2004"), 
                      X2 = 8:10), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2, by = "X1") %>%
    mutate(X2 = case_when(!is.na(X2.x) & !is.na(X2.y) ~ X2.y, 
                          is.na(X2.y)                 ~ X2.x, 
                          is.na(X2.x)                 ~ X2.y)) %>% 
    select(X1, X2)
```

**Explanation**

1. First you do a `full_join` on both data sets with `X1` as joining column. This creates column `X2.x` and `X2.y` which will bear the X2 values of the respective data sets.
2. Then it is just an easy application of `mutate` to select the right column depending on the rules you gave.

---

**Benchmark**

The `distinct` solution is by any means faster by a factor of `3`, as the following benchmark shows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(microbenchmark)
make_data_frame <- function(n, percent_matching = .1) {
   ids_a <- ids_b <- paste0("ID_", seq.int(n))
   non_matching_ids <- sample(n, round(n * (1 - percent_matching), 0))
   ids_b[non_matching_ids] <- paste(ids_b[non_matching_ids], "b", sep = "_")
   list(A = data.frame(X1 = ids_a, X2 = "a", stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
        B = data.frame(X1 = ids_b, X2 = "b", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

.distinct <- function(dfs) {
   bind_rows(dfs$B, dfs$A) %>% 
      distinct(X1, .keep_all = TRUE)
}

.join <- function(dfs) {
   full_join(dfs$A, dfs$B, by = "X1") %>%
      mutate(X2 = case_when(!is.na(X2.x) & !is.na(X2.y) ~ X2.y, 
                            is.na(X2.y)                 ~ X2.x, 
                            is.na(X2.x)                 ~ X2.y))
}
scenarios <- expand.grid(n = c(1e4, 1e5, 1e6),
                         percent_matching = c(.1, .5, .9))
all_data <- pmap(scenarios, make_data_frame)
all_mb <- map(all_data, ~ microbenchmark(.distinct(.x), .join(.x)))
map_dfr(seq.int(NROW(scenarios)), function(i) {
   mdat <- scenarios[i, ]
   my_summary <- summary(all_mb[[i]])
   rownames(mdat) <- NULL
   rownames(my_summary) <- NULL
   cbind(mdat, my_summary)
}) %>%
select(n, percent_matching, expr, mean)
```

---

```
#        n percent_matching          expr        mean
# 1  1e+04              0.1 .distinct(.x)    4.975013
# 2  1e+04              0.1     .join(.x)   12.587072
# 3  1e+05              0.1 .distinct(.x)   59.577142
# 4  1e+05              0.1     .join(.x)  149.987451
# 5  1e+06              0.1 .distinct(.x)    1.158597
# 6  1e+06              0.1     .join(.x)    2.699003
# 7  1e+04              0.5 .distinct(.x)    4.485196
# 8  1e+04              0.5     .join(.x)   11.902656
# 9  1e+05              0.5 .distinct(.x)   46.660016
# 10 1e+05              0.5     .join(.x)  132.180758
# 11 1e+06              0.5 .distinct(.x)  913.503111
# 12 1e+06              0.5     .join(.x) 2148.531600
# 13 1e+04              0.9 .distinct(.x)    4.299905
# 14 1e+04              0.9     .join(.x)   12.731292
# 15 1e+05              0.9 .distinct(.x)   37.558069
# 16 1e+05              0.9     .join(.x)  111.428117
# 17 1e+06              0.9 .distinct(.x)  458.030035
# 18 1e+06              0.9     .join(.x) 1458.408847
```